# All my AVD screen is in wide screen

Tags: android, android-emulator, orientation, android-studio, android-virtual-device

I tried different AVD Device Definitions from Android studio and created AVDs. All AVD's are ending up like this. How to solve this?

[image]

**Edit:** This occurs only if i change Target version to something like 3.0 (level 11). When i leave default target version 1.5 (level 3.0), the device is not created as wide screen. Is there a limitation to Target API level for chosen device?

Answer (score 0):

I think you might need to change the screen orientation using the ctrl+F11 shortcut.
For more shortcuts, please have a look at http://developer.android.com/tools/help/emulator.html.

Answer (score 0):

Try using those:

Switch to previous layout orientation (for example, portrait, landscape) `KEYPAD_7`, `Ctrl-F11`
Switch to next layout orientation (for example, portrait, landscape)    `KEYPAD_9`, `Ctrl-F12`

Take a look at the documentation on [controlling android emulator](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/emulator.html#controlling)

I hope it helped!

Comment: Thanks. As you can see this is not just about rotating the emulator. It's a portrait screen, but views are presented as landscape. I already tried rotating the emulator, that didn't solve.